# Fan problem after running sensors-detect

Tags: fan, samsung, fancontrol, lm-sensors

I ran `sensors-detect` and ever since the fan screams like crazy (100% all the time, even if the temperatures are very low). The only thing that works is to pull the charging out, then it assumes low power mode and the fan completely stops! (starts if something heavy is run, but again only 100% or 0)

When I ran `sensors-detect` I answered yes to all the questions (even the ones that had NO as default.

```
Laptop: Samsung Series 9 NP900x3c
OS: Ubuntu 17.04
```

UPDATE:
I now tried another fan in place of this one and it turns out that something went wrong with the fan and not the motherboard. Can it be that `sensors-detect` permanently / temporary damaged the fan feedback loop? (that's why now it can only run 0 or 100%)

My `/etc/modules` reads:

```
# Generated by sensors-detect on Wed Nov 29 00:10:47 2017
# Chip drivers
coretemp

# Generated by sensors-detect on Wed Nov 29 04:30:39 2017
# Chip drivers
coretemp
```

Comment: Would BIOS update / rewrite fix everything related to this matter?

Comment: Please update your post with output of `cat /etc/modules` (`sensors-detect` usually asks to write kernel module names here).